# JS namespace scopes: "this" inside "var" function evaluates to "window"

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, visibility

I have a class with some public methods and some private methods. The public methods are bound to "this" and the private method use "var".

I call the public method "do()" from outside the class, and there "this" evaluates to "MyClass". However, if I further call the private "something()" method, then "this" evaluates to the global namespace "Window";

```
function MyClass() {
    // private field
    var keys = ["foo", "bar"];

    // public method
    this.method = function(key) {
        alert(key);
    }

    // private method
    var something = function() {
        console.log("something()");
        console.log(this);
        $.each(keys, function(idx, key){
            this.method(key);
        }.bind(this));
    }

    // public method
    this.do = function() {
        console.log("do()");
        console.log(this);
        something();
    }
}

var test = new MyClass();
test.do();
```

The above code as a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lilalinux/13m242ce/8/

As I understand it, this.do (assigned inside the constructor) is a "privileged" function and as such should be callable from outside the class and be allowed to access private members (which are the vars and the parameters of the constructor).

Comment: `something` is a "free" function, not assocated with the instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: I thought it's a "free" function, if it doesn't use any of "var" or "this." and with "var" it is something like a private method? How do I declare private methods?

Comment: `var self = this` or `var something = function() {}.bind(this)`.

Comment: @dfsq I like the solution to bind the method the most, as it doesn't introduce another variable and the code "feels" more natural to someone with a JAVA/C/C++ background. If you make that answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `something` is not associated directly with `MyClass`, its `this` value will not refer to your `MyClass` instance.  What you should do instead is assign a reference to `this` outside of `something`, and refer to that variable within your private function.

Something like this:

```
function MyClass() {
    var self = this; // <-- keep the reference

    // ...

    // private method
    var something = function() {
        console.log("something()");
        console.log(self);
        $.each(keys, function(idx, key){
            self.method(key);
        }.bind(self));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Also consider using strict mode which will prevent variables from being implicitly attached to the `window` object. Just type `'use strict';` on top of your javascript files.

Comment: @DrinkBird That's only a concern for undeclared variables. `something = function() {..}` (no `var` declaration) would create an implicit global and `this` would automatically be set to `window`. The only difference strict mode would make on this kind of code is that `this` would be `undefined` if the function wasn't bound.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'm aware of that, I just mentioned it as a more general rule because it's easy to forget the `var` keyword and have something attached to `window` by mistake.